# Git actions branch

Tags: bash, github, github-actions

So I have two secrets:  DEV_SERVER_IP and MASTER_SERVER_IP.
in main.yml I need something like this

```
 run: echo "::set-env name=BRANCH_NAME::$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} | sed 's/\//_/g')"   

     run: ssh-keyscan -H ${{ secrets.BRANCH_NAME_SERVER_IP }} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

but am getting error

```
  env:
    BRANCH_NAME: dev
Error: Input required and not supplied: key
```

I need here something like this ssh-keyscan -H ${{ secrets.${BRANCH_NAME}_SERVER_IP }}

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use shell style logic inside a Github context
expansion (`${{ ... }}`) which won't work. Just move all your logic
into your shell script instead:

```
name: Example

on:
  push:

jobs:
  example:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: get target ip
        env:
          DEV_SERVER_IP: ${{ secrets.DEV_SERVER_IP }}
          MAIN_SERVER_IP: ${{ secrets.MAIN_SERVER_IP }}
        run: |
          branch_name=$(sed 's|/|_|g' <<< ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})
          target="${branch_name^^}_SERVER_IP"
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh
          ssh-keyscan -H ${!target} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

In the above workflow, the expression `${branch_name^^}` is a bash expression that returns the value of `$branch_name` in uppercase, and `${!target}` is a bash expression that returns the value of the variable who name is stored in `$target`.

Note that I'm not using your "set the `BRANCH_NAME` environment variable"
task because the `::set-env` command is [disabled by default for
security reasons](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. Am getting this error: Run branch_name=$(sed 's|/|_|g' <<< ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})
  branch_name=$(sed 's|/|_|g' <<< ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})
  target="${branch_name^^}_SERVER_IP"
  ssh-keyscan -H ${!target} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    BRANCH_NAME: dev
usage: ssh-keyscan [-46cDHv] [-f file] [-p port] [-T timeout] [-t type]
     [host | addrlist namelist]
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Comment: It looks like the example in your question was missing a `mkdir` command (the `~/.ssh` directory does not exist initially). I've updated this answer to use code that I've tested [here](https://github.com/larsks/sandbox/actions/runs/2988521932).

Comment: Same error: Run branch_name=$(sed 's|/|_|g' <<< ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})
  branch_name=$(sed 's|/|_|g' <<< ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})
  target="${branch_name^^}_SERVER_IP"
  mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  ssh-keyscan -H ${!target} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    BRANCH_NAME: dev
usage: ssh-keyscan [-46cDHv] [-f file] [-p port] [-T timeout] [-t type]
     [host | addrlist namelist]
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Comment: Can u se please this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73601065/git-actions-add-env-variables