# Git actions add ENV variables

Tags: bash, github, github-actions

I'm trying to add env variables and then use them.

```
name: Extract branch/server/ssh/project names into ENV variable
        shell: bash
        env:
          ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS: "true"
          SERVER_IP_DEV: ${{ secrets.SERVER_IP_DEV }}
          SERVER_IP_MASTER: ${{ secrets.SERVER_IP_MASTER }}
          EC2_SSH_KEY_DEV: ${{ secrets.EC2_SSH_KEY_DEV }}
          EC2_SSH_KEY_MASTER: ${{ secrets.EC2_SSH_KEY_MASTER }}
          PROJECT_NAME: ${{ secrets.PROJECT_NAME }}
        run: |
          branch=$(sed 's|/|_|g' <<< ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})
          server="SERVER_IP_${branch_name^^}"
          ssh_key="EC2_SSH_KEY_${branch_name^^}"
          project="PROJECT_NAME"
          echo "::set-env name=BRANCH_NAME::branch"
          echo "::set-env name=SERVER_IP::server"
          echo "::set-env name=SSH_KEY::ssh_key"
          echo "::set-env name=PROJECT_NAME::project"
```

and then use them somethin like this

```
 name: Install SSH Key
        uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
        with:
          key: ${SSH_KEY}
          known_hosts: "just-a-placeholder-so-we-dont-get-errors"
```

but it does not work. what am doing wrong?

Comment: In what way does it fail? Are there errors printed in the task output? The `::set-env` command is disabled by default; have you enabled it?

Comment: What you show here is going to result in the variable `SSH_KEY` having a value like `EC2_SSH_KEY_MASTER`, **not** the value of the `EC2_SSH_KEY_MASTER` variable (that's why we needed the `${!variable}` syntax in [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73600064/147356)).

Comment: I added ' ! ' but am still getting this error: Run ssh-keyscan -H ${!SERVER_IP} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  ssh-keyscan -H ${!SERVER_IP} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    BRANCH_NAME: branch
    SERVER_IP: server
    SSH_KEY: ssh_key
    PROJECT_NAME: project
usage: ssh-keyscan [-46cDHv] [-f file] [-p port] [-T timeout] [-t type]
     [host | addrlist namelist]
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Comment: i changed like this echo "::set-env name=BRANCH_NAME::${!branch}"  now i get     BRANCH_NAME: 
empty variables

Comment: You're referring to a variable `branch_name` in your action, but you're only ever setting a variable named `branch`. So `${branch_name^^}` will always be empty.

Comment: Note: *Git* doesn't have "actions" at all. These are *GitHub* actions. Refer to GitHub documentation. (In this case, though, you have a bash scripting issue.)

Comment: I fixed everything but now am getting Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). i think am doing something wrong here   - name: Install SSH Key
        uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
        env:
          EC2_SSH_KEY_DEV: ${{ secrets.EC2_SSH_KEY_DEV }}
          EC2_SSH_KEY_MASTER: ${{ secrets.EC2_SSH_KEY_MASTER }}
        with:
          key: EC2_SSH_KEY_${BRANCH_NAME^^}
          known_hosts: "just-a-placeholder-so-we-dont-get-errors"